# Angular 2 e2e Testing

Tags: angular, protractor, bootstrap-modal, e2e-testing

I just started with Angular 2 and e2e testing and I am trying to close a Bootstrap 4 modal by clicking in a blank area, using Protractor. I've tried:

```
it('should close the login modal when the blank space outside of the modal is clicked', () => {
  element(by.tagName('body')).click().then(function() {
    browser.sleep(250);
    expect(element(by.id('myModal')).isDisplayed()).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

...and I've even tried:

```
it('should close the login modal when the blank space outside of the modal is clicked', () => {
  browser.actions()
  .mouseMove(element(by.id('login_modal')), -20, -20)
  .click().then(function() {
    browser.sleep(250);
    expect(element(by.id('login_modal')).isDisplayed()).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

I'm new the the Angular 2 world, so the answer is probably obvious. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What's the question / the problem. Isn't it closing?

Comment: Correct. I am unable to click in a blank area and close the modal.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen your HTML, but I think this will happen. A `click`-action on an element will execute a click on the center of the element, see the [actions docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html).

It depends on how your modal is positioned on the page, but in common situations, a modal is in the center of the page. If we use that as a given and we execute the first click command you describe above, we will get the following

- click on the `body`, the body it the full screen, the center of the body will click on the modal => **modal will not be closed**

The second click command you describe fails because you need to provide an object, see [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/actions_exports_ActionSequence.html), so it needs to be

```js
browser.actions()
  .mouseMove(element(by.id('login_modal')), {
    x: toRight,
    y: toBottom
  })
  .click().then(function() {
    browser.sleep(250);
    expect(element(by.id('login_modal')).isDisplayed()).toBeFalsy();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback, which led me to the answer. I should have posted that this is a bootstrap modal, which is relevant. When called, the modal covers the whole page, not just the rectangle in the middle. By setting my coordinates to x:0, y:0 I was on the "blank" area of the modal.